# Present UIView on top of UITabBar

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I am drawing a custom view (UIDatePicker) over my table view which is nested within a UITabBarController. When I add my custom view as below, it gets clipped by the tab bar.

```
[self.view addSubview:customDateView];
```

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to go around this? Can I hide the tab bar?

Thanks in advance,
Ricky.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem, just set the view's hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property to YES.

Comment: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed belongs to UIViewController and not to UIView